# eventhandler seems to create new threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, eventhandler

I'm working with the FileSystemWatcher class and noticed that the eventhandler for the created event operates on a seperate thread. I am trying to understand multithreaded programming and was under the impression that the only thread you get for free is the Main thread.

I thought that when you want to have another thread you need to explicitly create it. I am puzzled why the code in the eventhandler method is running in different threads than the main thread.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher w = new FileSystemWatcher(@"c:\test\");       
        w.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
        w.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    private static void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
       Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

I hope somebody can clarify this for me. Thanks

Comment: "the FileSystemWatcher class" ... which language is that?

Comment: I mean the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher in C#

Comment: Please find the button to edit your question then! There are people that only filter on the languages they are interested in, so they won't even see your question. I just happened to pop across it due to the multithreading flag, for example, but I now next to nothing about C# (or Java, as JimN guessed).

Comment: Yes I did assume Java, although my answer should still be applicable for c# and probably most other languages/platforms.

Comment: Your main thread is sitting there waiting for input from the console; it can't possibly execute a callback method on behalf of the `FileSystemWatcher`

Comment: Not necessarily, @Servy. If you take a look at win32's `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` function, you will see that it's possible to block waiting for something and at the same time service a message loop. Of course it's not really "at the same time", but but waiting for input and executing callbacks can be handled the same way and without additional threads.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt But the main thread has setup no message loop in the first place, nor is it processing that message loop.  It is instead waiting for input from the console.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that the thread set up a message, sorry for the misunderstanding. I just wanted to show an example where a thread seems to be blocked waiting for something to happen and actually in the background performs some other tasks. In other words, I don't say that your result is faulty, but your reasoning is.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstood.  It is *not the case* that the only threads in the system are those that you explicitly create.  You may use other APIs or libraries (including the "core" libraries that come with Java), and those libraries are free to create whatever threads they need in order to implement and provide the services they advertise.  In many cases, there is no other way than for them to create their own threads.

Some examples:

1. The file watcher service you're using.  Something needs to interact with the operating system and detect that something in the filesystem has changed.  The monitoring and callback is happening asynchronously to (that is, in parallel and not tied to the timing of) your main thread.
2. Swing (GUI).  This must run on another thread so that the UI can do work (and remain responsive) even while other threads such as the main thread are doing other things.
3. The garbage collector thread runs in the background and periodically reclaims memory to be reused.
4. etc.

**Edit:**

To respond to your question about how to know when an api will use its own threads for callbacks:

1. Check the documentation.  For good quality apis such as the core
   apis, this sort of thing is often documented.
2. As a general rule of thumb you can assume that any api which makes callbacks will use its own threads to do so (this is usually but not always the case).
3. Try to learn (or anticipate, or guess) how the library works internally.  Once again, the documentation is a good place to start.  If you learn that it has its own threads, and if it makes callbacks, then it's highly likely those callbacks are going to happen on those threads.
4. Use some common sense.  The api cannot use your (main or other) thread to make callbacks to you, unless you first call into the api.  And for this to work over some arbitrary period of time, the api would need to monopolize your thread for that period of time, meaning that you would not be able to use the thread for anything else.

Comment: I see, How do you recognize such the code blocks? I now that I have to use a thread safe queue to collect these events. But it would be nice to know this in advance. Is there some general rule for this?

Comment: The question is about C#, not Java.  That said, *most* everything does apply anyway, consider adjusting the discrepancies for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Yeah if I had experience with C# I might do that. Sorry!